# Can Application be rejected by using native css from Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, css, xcode4.5

My client's application is rejected by apple which I have developed, he sent me not enough information but he just sent me reference number on apple review guide line 2.5 which says "Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected", I checked external APIs on my project but all of them public except Native CSS which I don't have idea that whether apple accept this or not. My application is not very big its a small project. I also asked the client to send me detail info so that I can sniff in better way. If any one has idea about native css please guide me. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policy, not programming.


Answer (score 2):

Apple does not reject an application because the user interface is built using HTML. In fact, many Apple apps or advertising platforms for iOS are entirely built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. For instance, the Apple Store and iAd advertising platform, among others, use HTML as the primary medium for the user interface. Outside of Apple there are many successful apps that have user interfaces built with HTML, including LinkedIn, Wikipedia, the BBC Olympics, and many, many others.

Apple rejects applications that do not:

```
have a user experience that feels like an "app"
feel "at home" in the iOS ecosystem
offer a differentiation from a mobile web experience
```

This applies to all apps, not just apps developed using HTML for the UI. Adobe is not Apple, so we do not know the exact approval rules beyond the "App Review Guidelines" and "App Store Review Guidelines" provided by Apple. However, it is clear that approval largely comes down to the user experience: how the user interacts with the app and how it "feels" on the device.

know more about this from [Dealing with apple app rejection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-application-rejections-and-phonegap-advice.html)